# How to implement stickyfloat.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement `stickyfloat.js` because it looked like a very straight forward way to get sticky nave bar which is what I really need to move on with the sites development.

For the life of me I cannot get it to work, I have tried numerous demos, examples and user guides but there is obviously something small I am missing. When implementing the theory in fiddle, it works. When I add my code, it doesn't - I really don't get it.

You can see the live site [here](http://energyamplified.co.za/home.php) or the Fiddle implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mLbZH/44/)

```
<script src="js/stickyfloat.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yes, if you do go to the live site, excuse the layout :( I cannot start fine tuning the layout until I know what affect the sticky nav bar is going to have on the site.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling stickyfloat on your live website. Could you give a pointer? On jsFiddle you do ' $('.flotant-compartir').stickyfloat({...})'. I'd expect something like ('.home').stickyfloat({...}) on your live

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but it seems like a simple `position: fixed` on the `div.menu` might do the trick, without any JS code?

Comment: Hi Spork, thank youfor your time.

Comment: Whoops, hit enter. thank you for your time. I am using $('.menu').stickyfloat({ (cannot see where in fiddle you see flotant)? however, that references the div I have containing the menu - are you saying I need to call that on-site as well?

Comment: Hi Lucero, thank you for your time. I didn't actually think of that - tried it and did the trick. Before I retain this route, what would the point be of doing this via Jquery then if a simple css fix does the same thing (and wiith no JS reliance as well) - are there any drawbacks?

Comment: @Byron if by 'on-site' you mean during execution, then yes. You need to instantiate this call on your site. In a javascript <script>block</script>. Simple fixed may or may not work, depending on your needs.

Comment: guys, I am sorry - I do apologize but I copied in the wrong fiddle location. My site is hosted here http://jsfiddle.net/mLbZH/86/

Comment: @Byron, I don't think that there are may drawbacks with this approach since `position:fixed` is nowadays quite well supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed - The JS/jQuery approach is usually required when you need to have a mixed model, for instance some sidebar which first scrolls with the background but then stays sticky on the screen when scrolling further.

Comment: Hi Lucero, Thank you for the meaningful insight, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing the call to stickyfloat here... I can't find $('.menu').stickyfloat({}) anywhere on the site.

Comment: @ Spork - okay, that did the trick! I added the function into the html on-site and it did the trick!!! I need to tweak the settings as it is not at the top of the screen but the method is now working. Thank you so much for your help, mail me when you are in Cape Town for your beers :)

Comment: hahah will do. Keep in mind that the idea of stickyfloat is 'relative to the parent'. Meaning, right now your header doesn't come out of it's parent 'div.content'. You now have three blocks inside of content overflowing it, but stickyfloat will not co-operate. Take another look at the height of your containers within .content.

Comment: Hi Spork, Thanks - I noticed this yesterday as well and have resolved this issue. Now just trying to find a way to change the text color depending on which anchor Id it is in, I am currently resulting to a ugly gray since the text color has to change. I am investigating this issue (it actually doesn't seem like it is possible) so will be sure to post a new question on here if I dont come right.